# SortedList using a string notation but sorted numerically

Tags: c#, sorting, sortedlist

I noticed that sorted list of key int sorts values numerically

```
SortedList < int,double> sl0 = new SortedList<int,double>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  sl0.Add(i, 0.01);

[0, 0.01]
[1, 0.01]
[2, 0.01]
[3, 0.01]
[4, 0.01]
[5, 0.01]
[6, 0.01]
[7, 0.01]
[8, 0.01]
[9, 0.01]
[10, 0.01]
[11, 0.01]
[12, 0.01]
[13, 0.01]
[14, 0.01]
[15, 0.01]
[16, 0.01]
[17, 0.01]
[18, 0.01]
[19, 0.01]
```

and sorted list of key string sorts values alphabetically

```
SortedList < string,double> sl1 = new SortedList<string,double>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  sl1.Add(i.ToString(), 0.01);

[0, 0.01]
[1, 0.01]
[10, 0.01]
[11, 0.01]
[12, 0.01]
[13, 0.01]
[14, 0.01]
[15, 0.01]
[16, 0.01]
[17, 0.01]
[18, 0.01]
[19, 0.01]
[2, 0.01]
[3, 0.01]
[4, 0.01]
[5, 0.01]
[6, 0.01]
[7, 0.01]
[8, 0.01]
[9, 0.01]
```

Is there any way to have a **nested** key that would be sorted numerically for instance the order has to look like this for the keys. First I imagined that I can use strings like that, but for sure they are sorted alphabetically:

```
//Keys
//"0;0"
//"0;0;0"
//"0;1"
//"0;2"
//"0;10"
//"0;10;1;0;0"
//"1;0"
//"2;1"
//"3;1"
//"3;1;2"
```

For now I have a class that inherits sorted list:

```
public class Plates : Comparer<int[]> , IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Plate>>{


    //Store all plates as a sorted list
    //String is use for storing groups
    //i.e. 0, 1, 2 ... fn
    //i.e. 0;0, 0;1, 0;2, 1;3, 1;4, 1;5 ... gn_fn
    private SortedList<string, Plate> sortedPlates;



    public Plates() {
        sortedPlates = new SortedList<string,Plate>();
    }

    #region IEnumerable Implementation
    public void Add(Plate item) => sortedPlates.Add(item.fID, item);
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,Plate>> GetEnumerator() =>  sortedPlates.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    #endregion

    #region IComparer


    public override int Compare(int[] x, int[] y) {

        int[] a = x.Length < y.Length ? x : y;
        int[] b = x.Length < y.Length ? y : x;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
                return a[i].CompareTo(b[i]);
        }

        return 0;

    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_SortedList_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__), you'll notice there's a constructor that has an `IComparer<TKey>` parameter. You can create any kind of comparer class you want to control the sorting methodology.

Comment: Would it be possible show how to implement such Comparer? I have never worked with IComparer before.

Comment: Please, begin to read documentation. You'll find your answers much faster if you start doing that before asking questions. If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) for `IComparer<T>`, there's example code right there for you.

Comment: I tried and updated solution but am quite lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom comparer:

```
class KeyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xs = x.Split(';');
        var ys = y.Split(';');

        int min = Math.Min(xs.Length, ys.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++)
        {
            int cmp = xs[i].CompareTo(ys[i]);

            if (cmp != 0)
                return cmp;
        }

        return xs.Length.CompareTo(ys.Length);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
var list = new SortedList<string, double>(new KeyComparer());

list.Add("0;1", 0);
list.Add("0;0;0", 0);
list.Add("0;10;1;0;0", 0);
list.Add("0;2", 0);
list.Add("0;10", 0);
list.Add("1;0", 0);
list.Add("3;1;2", 0);
list.Add("2;1", 0);
list.Add("3;1", 0);
list.Add("0;0", 0);

foreach (var x in list)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: I had to cast string to integer to get a good sequence, but your answer pointed me to the right direction. Thank you very much, especially for the code and not impolite comments as previous person did. Have a good day.

        int a = Convert.ToInt32(xs[i]);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(ys[i]);
        
        //int cmp = xs[i].CompareTo(ys[i]);
         int cmp = a.CompareTo(b);